# Get months in Snowflake without having the timezone

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a column that contains a timestamp with the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS .

I need to get only the month. I am well aware that MONTHNAME exists, but it seems to me that it only works if the timestamp includes the timezone.

In the current situation, I'm trying to obtain it using the following:

```
SELECT
 nameofthecolum, date_part (month, nameofthecolum),
  
FROM
 tablename
```

And I get the error:

> ERROR: column "month" does not exist
> Position: 32

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the data type of `nameofcolum` is a timestamp?  I'm not able to reproduce this issue using the following: `select current_timestamp() as nameofcolum, date_part(month,nameofcolum) as month_number;`

Comment: Also, don't leave a space between the function `date_part` and the `(`

Comment: The error says "month" column does not exist but your statement does not use any column named "month". I also see there is a syntax error, the last comma should be removed. So that means you are not sharing the exact query with us.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract month number like that

```
SELECT
 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM nameofthecolum)
  
FROM
 tablename
```

to get month name in snowflake

```
SELECT to_varchar(nameofthecolum, 'MMMM')
FROM
 tablename;
```

for PostgreSQL or Oracle

```
SELECT to_char(nameofthecolum, 'month')
FROM
 tablename;
```

for MySQL users

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(nameofthecolum, '%M')
FROM
 tablename;
```

Comment: Why are you answering for multiple dialects? The question is tagged as Snowflake.

Comment: sorry, added query for snowflake, as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MONTHNAME()` function with any temporal data type (`TIMESTAMP_NTZ`, `TIMESTAMP_LTZ`, `TIMESTAMP_TZ`, and `DATE`) and any timestamp format compliant to your `TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT` parameter. There's no restriction about the existence of a time zone.

**Example 1: MONTHNAME()**

```
create or replace table t1 (ts timestamp_ntz) as
select '2021-01-01 00:00:00';

select monthname(ts) from t1;
-- Jan

select monthname(ts::timestamp_ltz) from t1;
-- Jan

select monthname(ts::timestamp_tz) from t1;
-- Jan

select monthname(ts::date) from t1;
-- Jan
```

If you want to extract the month number instead of the month name, you can use `DATE_PART()` as you already tried.

**Example 2: DATE_PART()**

```
create or replace table t1 (ts timestamp_ntz) as
select '2021-01-01 00:00:00';

select date_part(month, ts) from t1;
-- 1

select date_part(month, ts::timestamp_ltz) from t1;
-- 1

select date_part(month, ts::timestamp_tz) from t1;
-- 1

select date_part(month, ts::date) from t1;
-- 1
```

Also, regarding the error you encountered:

> ERROR: column "month" does not exist Position: 32

This error message format is different from Snowflake's error format. This is more like PostgreSQL.

If you are using any application or intelligent client that supports multiple database products and can switch the connection target easily, I'd recommend you to check whether the application is actually connected to Snowflake or not.